# How can non-earth-orbiting satellite coordinates be obtained by amateurs?

Tags: coordinate, satellite, tracker

Just a few hours ago the moon-bound spacecraft [Chandrayaan-3](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2382565-indias-chandrayaan-3-launches-to-explore-moons-water-rich-south-pole/) was launched.

While it will orbit Earth [for a few days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-3#/media/File:Animation_of_Chandrayaan-3_around_Earth.gif), it is accelerating/changing its orbit often to prepare for the transfer to a lunar orbit, so its coordinates (especially from a specific location on Earth's surface) are very unpredictable.

Neither an orbital element approach nor [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)s will work here reliably unless they are updated very frequently (the latter only seem to work for earth-orbiting satellites anyway).

In the future, there will probably exist more moon-orbiting spacecraft like the [Lunar Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Gateway) which will also change its orbit often. Does a publicly accessible website/API exist that provides the current coordinates for such objects?

In this case it seems ESA's Estrack network is supporting the tracking of this probe, but it doesn't seem like they have a public API: https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/ESA_ground_stations_support_Chandrayaan-3_Moon_mission

Edit: [Permalink](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydGGtT20jyO1X8h4lYVpIjFD8g2VWd6taAqLAL2GV7s5tzXCrZHmMlsqSMRhCg-EH3O-6PXffM6OEHSdWSYEv9nn5NN5qmkQHlLKR3lNzRGU8YmQc8IAuWrMj7hIWPSZyRBYCTmBL4WiWMEh6wW8rJNJmHNNvfI_DDaBTwEKTwhAQxSaYZZXcASWIyozGnzALwnPAljWeUpFHC8ZlwFnwWaktBYUw65yTPwviWnP7vv48hZWSWszua2WR_T9L8xULOaUymD6R_TdoDpG032227-c5utSRNMA9STudIc5eE82Mk6JDf84i03u7vaXBwlBau0oRxsN6C3685zTiYIQ6_yGOwK4kyomgilvuzYLakiiCEQ60RpCyZ5zOu0OBGysMVLbDFu0XwE9xKUX_OIuISbcl5mjlv3mTZ3P6cRnYcZIF9m9y9CdLwzVKFwV-EEbUBou3vwad_R1mG_gX-lt2U55kGGfVnqzkCNaC77v7h-V7_vXftfvSG-3u909_98-6o69709vcG3oU__DgcAfLybHCxvycI_dHHvud-8M5GvQFwwIM_6p5eeW57f-8Vvp31BgPgv_Ek8qp76l0NhUCBPveuRl1_JAG9P0f-nzeXo6H7x_XR-f7e2fCDf9EbXHdH0p4iDr-V3jVWwbcsfKRuGHOj3TTN_b05XZAF5bOlj7lpyOyzyrxKoyAGt2YA5_iVpPhJU9ORmSDdsRD-OOtdX3dvzl39SUp51gHm3Yy8AYCkQAShZ_pX3RsPoEI8Aoej7mDkjy6vESq0SWivXwGTVMK8vj-8_I-EUQET6uvmvPrpp2Hv4glen5-KsD0D0OtdKMqDlKETAG4WRfYVWItEtdMk4wZkkCVq1n3SoU5XAdcdonP6jevPFsGUyQATxmmOCEMHabqFRpjPSmqVR4zaGQ3YbGkwrdu_JB-8wfCyd-N8yhrGp2HD1ESV2CjctG9ZkqdGSwkJF6WcVy6ppacKAv7I4yy0vwIWQ8k6BHUUXGFGntQz2D3NsT8ALJuxMOWIxSb0VBP8rJllQ1htGG_8OzM__fQJHOwZdkM8ej2vbn5p9Qpl30A5bhmq3fSIqAhvcDnUzE30higZH56zWEiTQNFLXbIqnTVuOZPS6oOdghRUPyQ6aZDjpgJHYUwzGX1BbWdpFHIBNdY5tU-xZn9OwtgQ2PGJ0zqZmJWzGJTTlrtCE3LeG3g3Zx65GHSvPQJlQs56vcH55U135A2FH7PG8GE1TSKyogGG8DsJoWwZ0AVloudfsAC6oSNYFmVCC4cJN6F5WOkgiwUzLmsdPywChYqvkMkXQZRBrcP14osKdNHX8p3Gc_FWlL3yPX7t8JXCjjOJM3RLN8fOUWsi8izDawhJJsqzCGTJfQF2ihxI7iu_CoN8MEVqFd3ezjhL8cEoTbaIdvjx6HB6dDgnh--dw2vNtBmFLjOjBn8M40XiFjeEnfOZshdO913RgP9nglW0kgwuplsuWgmF51kSJQzVjSdW7VdSb3qjqgAoqDJYNbDyONzhQZqCqdAEnkDAuDV5Jk-LKAmEK8fNiflcLzRxcJkOFJumZFER0wikUtsct0uArZkgYp29qAmvECMSUMixKtkbOuEUVTBxbCm8j88V5l-7glHK3AqHczj8QURQolK14TxxcYiQFB7UGJ1v-QqK48eMDzSKkvs67wFR7sE8CMXQ9jM05iiZhfyh1t4g5JAQMl65KdIgxyRAf7adSc31IKfQJ8dKEV-nMzFraiHfdhB1nIlpx3iTRTAGzA1zvVe8kKlYhAfkNA-jOTmltalRNpUpfTQKzqJBwLsPr3CkxzCtsArZhLcm4GIIqKFIC0ukH9Ii16QiUStVfcAQwtE3irUWFqQMppmRkiNQY5I3pLPmYxs0ok9AAXkNRjTAMKTl4mFSc6Cai5UPsRltBasek-JIaNqaT9UBpA_PWXBPAhzCp8k3i9yHfEmSVCQGBWezGK5fwP9MptK19yGjPpAa0KinFmk0vtwXHr5DCxpqLjYa6GYkMk1lVR_w2JU7cNi7cSh7b4heM5pWy-pYbatpTpTMguX1izzH1on1znprHe_iyfKVofi4wgpWESS07G7sHAPf3fjYmWzkXF_OqCGOhwFO-HjuVQA3LJLJi0jD_eII9ouj1jvS_MVpNjU5jK5jWscFhgKmtdLql9k6ZdNpnmjV3baObDnNjmahejm1ulrn11-BWo61masdtU5-kQRpEFFYl1xtGuVwV8ryx1t4rvA44EIkhjSSVTjWvVkEU1c4g0lRF_c2Ppwm8wfifc0DoNHBU5mi9_lDSl2dBfMw0U1pEyaUO2Kob57w8t4Wg_2JRaJgSiNf-KDTFBwL1FJwBOyLekwh2VLQAptlISPIeeLnKVa_BJlOeQVD445hszRQJ26rwg5ze7KTRyUBbHU0yLhcbhdkjU3bHuwKNcXmsbVy1IJZBg48K-nxjoA8MxVf_TVJ62-09lbKWweB3AJQNwl06b_p0DXUa2Gwygo18Ei-atBR2NokpOpTZc4LbApbZysVQs3jXi_XCr0WRR1jVHsXdxbRYUNeJrcsSJeQdMrmJV2hah3TQbDhg6KPwtsl16tJmvRh3uUiv5QBeFh8hRm6Rd_u1CrQlYgz8BlT7Am7BX7oQgT_m1W7SlEP9BAgUOmcFneQqxyCY0wpFr312SLV0oqUJrqPxvkK2gmnBnYfFQOr8CouCmY9c9XA-k_24LXxTMjZXnmqLF-j_kxclzTF3FPVLG54zQ3elwfI787zssqrDrhdPq76rp1ix5hTqffh_4-0bm0R31FbRrLwH_SIDeXifikSQ1iykRgy6GtiRIvZkIO5IkjFJoU5klFY_4UjzR1zndA7FcMOKMYRZ5wKIV-sdD3DwChTaBWyxl8mrlspwsH-BT6ceV7mM9fOJ2Bb7qqyZpfT8FLG5RHMF5EZh42KYcegz2qQFg7766O_haPNIom58L_27SiDITLanJKlo0McqjadNHacmv7aznyw6ygHIvOKnfsK0VmhbB2n9vExrD2h03l2yFP2rNUIS5OydZOkU9aNqpslnZguYcU2oFnBP1Ml37HdfkuPTooICWTLXNv5pjC0QaX07WmSx3PY5sUUV9r_90fZUWqa8M-2ECpoiY2xmOYaKMOcjJ32pNCkHQRBgGNLGuD24Dbt9kkpc7Sk5PXfJPgWZjvGOdFTDRQJ25kIp2i-NdEnJyeFgyEgYmaopZUQVo6jwraS9ZZRGtf-YtS3s2Vyb8ixQ_UDceO44tOq3WBu9QjHitFa0bfM_wO739BS&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to the code I adapted from PM 2Ring below, to color observed orbit segments

Comment: JPL have a pre-launch planning trajectory  https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-158 Let me see what it looks like...

Comment: NASA also sometimes publishes SPICE kernels with the trajectory.

Comment: Chandrayaan-3 has a NORAD ID: 57320 and you can track the live location of it here https://www.n2yo.com/?s=57320&live=1

Comment: @DimaChubarov This doesn't seem to match up with the JPL Horizons data - with which I apparently just managed to image it - what is their data source?

Comment: At the bottom of the page they refer in particular to Celestrak from which TLEs can be obtained as follows: http://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gp.php?CATNR=57320

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think TLE's will work here at least in the long term because they are only intended for Earth-orbiting spacecraft. Also, since it is often accelerating to raise its orbit, the TLE is probably out of date because of this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does a publicly accessible website/API exist that provides the current coordinates for such objects?

Yes! There's a pre-launch planning trajectory from ISRO/JPLNAV in the [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) system. Chandrayaan-3 has ID number -158. It's classed as a major body, so we can use it as an observation centre, not just a target. There's some info [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-158).

This preliminary trajectory covers from 2023-Jul-14 09:23 to 2023-Sep-13 09:00. The data on Horizons will be updated as the mission proceeds, but not in real time.

Here's a view looking from above (north) of the ecliptic plane, from 2023-Jul-15 0:00 UTC, using a 1 hour time step. Earth is blue, the Moon is yellow, the spacecraft is red. The grey line is the X axis, which points towards the First Point of Aries (the equinox point). The plotted points are connected with cubic Bézier curves, using the normalised velocity vectors to compute Bézier control points.

[image: Earth, Moon, Chandrayaan-3]

This trajectory has a significant component in the north-south axis:

[image: Side-on view showing N-S component]

These are screenshots from this [interactive 3D plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydWP1y4kYS_99VvMOsvIkkVpb5MMmFKtUF23LFiQ0UkE32MKUSMBg5QqMdjfBX8UD3HPdi1z0zAoG9uaqj1qDp6e75TX9rDcMgAyp4RNeUrOlMME7moQjJgrMV-YXx6IUlGVkAmSWUwM-KcUpEyO-pIFM2j2hWOSLw4TQORQRaBCNhQtg0o3wNFJaQGU0E5Q6Q50QsaTKjJI2ZwGciePggj90qihLSvCR5FiX35Pw__36JKCeznK9p5pLKkeL5g0dC0IRMn0n_ljQGyNuoNRpu7Ue3Xq8cGXAt5I1WKeMCsDnw9zWnmYBD5NUWeQKnsjgjmifmeTALZ0uqGSKAvMeQcjbPZ0LqzXlMPGIshUiz9ulpls3dhzR2kzAL3Xu2Pg3T6HSpjRcsopi6QDEqR_AdrCnP0CogX3drCuc0zGgwW82RaADfbec3P_D7v_i33hd_WDnqnf8aXHZGHa_bqxwN_Ktg-GU4gs3ri8FV5UgyBqMvfd_77F-MegOQgIdg1Dm_8b1G5egDri56gwHId321edM592-GUqHcvvRvRp1gpAi930fB793r0dD77fbksnJ0MfwcXPUGt52RwlPY9-et1axV-JRFL9SLEmE1arZdOZrTBVlQMVsGGFGWihlnGw1pHCbglwzoAn9Yit80tdvKx8ocC2mPi97tbad76ZmvSsvGBJrfHfkDICmFSELL9G86XR-oUj0Sh6POYBSMrm-RKk9T1F5_R2Spovn9YHj9L0WjkiaPL8P58PHjsHf1CsvNa-G2DRD93pXmPE45GgHodpEaX0G0CEA3ZZmwIIIcmWneqwnZtQqF2SamoE_C3DgEQyaDnShJc9ywTNBmOgjC3mituzji1M1oyGdLixud_jX57A-G171u-y6rWnfDqm3I6HdRue3ec5anVl0riRZbPR88UgpP7QT8qOssjD9CnkCitQmeUUhFGXnVz4B7mmNWAy2b8SgVuIul47WkeGPY2zReHYC3_pnZdx_vwMC-5Vblo9_zy_C3qFeouws16Q1Qo9sjMiP8wfXQsA-3D1Qp_4icJ1KbIsoK6JHV1ljjenuyRX38riJNNb8jJqmSs5omx1FCM-V9ye1maRwJSbU0i4Z9lxjuA4sSS26OW-16a2LvbMUhm95YK7Ih5P2B373wydWgc-sTyBJy0esNLq-7nZE_lGbMqsPn1ZTFZEVD9ODfxIPGMqALymWhvuLhipK2FFls41naS1oJ4WGigy4ezoRKdfxyCOQpLiGQr8I4o0Vea-PizzvG0LvjTO1ZpmPa4_ZJfSIDKcPugCwTbXQkcvZYkNuFk9njznKQbw4R90Lmm3TGeOLoP8VxqGUXGhBp22uUyBoptKQwTWkyh-x4BQXj-mRDXhcxCyWEcW1ib8oReEx8ZSbEFMne-D1kUsxmkXguxSNAAZBKT25LeDmCQ52N9mRSimm2haC6tzy33ZzYpWPh7u8wNdsT202w9MRQt-eWve_dQ6uhNY_JeR7Fc3JOS11Z-X9KX6xCpPA0rANYwl1eonS3qzdrsKrBXgKhY2nWAoIyQFrTN1UHScftHAbtQqBRtGjJO8gZTjMrJSdwjE1OSXPPuC6ciMaAA8gnAFEFYMgr5MOkZDk9d2jjYVS98VLZGcWVENqeMfUFlA0vefhIQhxypuzJIY-RWBKWyoigZMZ4AoUS9r8nU2Xax4jTAFgtyKmpQ6rVvx4LC68RQVVPJlYVzYxMtq1R9WEf06sJl12PI5VEEVrNqjl1p-k0nJo90ToLkU_flDlzWs6Pzg_O2XsyWb6ytJzQu1JUOgmRrcftM5Bbj8_ak4Ng66tpIsJGDumh7r0KoRgim2zangEDXvPk1zw-qbcMNTBo2pCmJ_WmocYHz6jPDQfF1FzgGc2ffoI9NThksKzVHQI6_qG40jCmMEt6xjTOYRx5pnHMHrHaaS1yjgAzDmmscmds-rMYmls0g4ZsyvqID-ds_kz8r3kIPCZcM9P8gXhOqWfycB4x01bAMBq8Ecfz5gwwqUc5PrUcEodTGgfyLi3Jv8AzCv6Q_6UfU4iTFM6AoVtVWJiwc8GCPMWMLYrutgxCKUtg6LbwRBzkJQr7bftUFyUhjMQ0zISa-xdkT8x42z2LY4rx7s1cBzZUe24G7xupZWue8pKl5RXdrsqqQY_5swmJq5fFwdrBunkouV3T0LulrqJTRPv_G2J6tyy26yuc4auLmsHMkjdMtHVpTSh4gpjwErFk9zxMlxA6GvOSrvBoE90qxfBB88fR_VKYu7GD9GE6EDJMNAC8LC5h4KjTH949VW7vVFyAzbgWZ_we5KEQEPxn7ypGiudAGgODjsoUCuOMxYx72iDY2rZq0VoPDtlN-Mhpo_lokq8gowW1sABoHziFVXGqsssRqJv___PSsNeypZ638-EuWve4H4jnkZp8O92lHo7DtQPZt4PE3049mKUlXOiObyoM_pcylc1bkxcXhaQ80ClrceFBecCBB5V39tTInH5Pz1Q2elC01973NR1i2tnwPY3YJXDwBJ2Rg41ywRIhERpPJxnMInG5tqiPbEDYovciCuCM2-3daeVh-VswtqP2De5mb98OdlP4GEa6qN3ctMlrtjHKkDScbB-OdNMBoDKkKXRwcHLfnbI8mcMULlt68fJA_vyiYrvUUPH_SMBMkJzVsWztVdRhT8btxqRwgXEchiF0N5aGOEN6NbfR2uocLSn59CcJn6Lsnd4us9tClTC2Qj7rMlBS3Wq1jN0bl-xCJVtKZdvZRGLbit5zSpPSi17fzZbs0VKNTPcqWfs8-e2Uaqm3e4RrJYhWZdJ_AfyvZ3A=&lang=sage).
There's some info on how to use that plotting script [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49823/16685).

Note that you can set the Moon (ID 301) as the center. I recommend a start time of Aug-10, and you should probably toggle off the `curve` plotting.

---

FWIW, here's a [query URL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&EPHEM_TYPE=V&OUT_UNITS=KM-S&REF_PLANE=E&VEC_LABELS=NO&CSV_FORMAT=YES&OBJ_DATA=NO&VEC_TABLE=2&COMMAND=-158&CENTER=%40399&START_TIME=%272023-Jul-14+9%3A30+UTC%27&STOP_TIME=%272023-Sep-13+8%3A00%27&STEP_SIZE=1d) which returns the position & velocity vectors (in the J2000.0 ecliptic frame), using a 1 day time step.

Comment: This is a great answer, I will try to use the Horizons data (via astroquery: https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jplhorizons/jplhorizons.html) to attempt to photograph it today :) I will not yet mark it as answer though in case anyone has info on *live* tracking data

Comment: @2080 Glad you like it. Astroquery is good, but it's pretty easy to construct Horizons queries & parse the results yourself.

Comment: @uhoh Ah, right. :) BTW, vector tables use TDB by default, but you can put `UTC` or `TT` after the start time to request a different time scale.

Comment: Thanks to you, we now have this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7LAFiUXLMo :)

Comment: @2080 That's pretty cool! Perhaps you can post it as a GIF (at a slower frame rate), either here or on https://space.stackexchange.com The Stack Exchange image uploader accepts GIF, but it has a file size limit of 2 MB.

Comment: Uploaded here: https://deeprandomsurvey.org/static/img/Chandrayaan-3.gif
In the meantime I have found this SkyTrack software which can continuously track from JPL Horizons Ephemerides as well: https://heavenscape.com/videos.html

Comment: We observed it two more times, last just now on its lunar transfer trajectory: https://deeprandomsurvey.org/ - thank you very much for your answer and for the code that helps us visualize the orbits!

Comment: Here is my adapted code that colors a segment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=exuezf

Comment: Ah, good to know! I'll add the permalink to my question

Answer (score 2):

SPICE kernels are available for many NASA (and other missions).  [A large collection](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/) is available from NAIF.  As well as some [archived datasets](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_archived.html).  These can be processed using the [SPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html) toolkit, which is available for several programming languages directly from NAIF.  Additional 3rd party libraries like [SpiceyPy](https://github.com/AndrewAnnex/SpiceyPy) are also available.