Is the barycenter of Jupiter and its moons always inside Jupiter?
Is the barycenter of Jupiter always inside of Jupiter? If not, then how often does it leave Jupiter?

Jupiter is massive. The Jupiter system barycentre is always well inside Jupiter, close to the core. Here's a typical Horizons distance plot (TDB timescale, 6 hour timestep), showing a mean core-barycentre distance ~116 km. The nominal equatorial radius of Jupiter (where the atmospheric pressure equals 1 bar) is ~71490 km.


I've written lots of Horizons scripts, but the distance scripts are often useful. :)

I have various plotting scripts here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49823/16685 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55927/16685

You really do like your plotting scripts then:)

@Starship :) Take a look at the equivalent plots for the other giant planets.
